# Applying ST to Antlr4-generated parse trees

Tags: antlr4, stringtemplate-4

Generated accessors of parse tree context nodes do not conform getProperty()/isProperty()/hasProperty() standard. As a result, ST can’t be applied to the parse tree directly.  There seems to be 3 alternatives to apply ST to the generated parse trees:

1. Create ST model adapter classes for each generated context node. Then ST can be applied directly to the generated parse tree. *Duplicate work here is creating model adapters.*
2. For every parse tree node create a wrapper node that conforms getProperty()/isProperty()/hasProperty() standard. Then ST can be applied to wrapper nodes. *Duplicate work here is creating wrapper nodes.* (In this case parse tree is not even required; auto-parse-tree construction could be turned off and wrapper (AST) nodes could be created in grammar actions).
3. Create a Visitor. Each visit*() instantiates an ST specific to a context node being visited, sets parameters (which could be STs returned by visiting child nodes or simple strings) and returns the ST.  This is the option I’m currently using. *Duplicate work here is creating visitor and assigning template parameters in code.*

**Is there an Antlr4 option that generates accessors of parse tree context nodes that conform getProperty()/isProperty()/hasProperty() standard? Or is there an ST4 option that allows it accessing property() instead of looking for getProperty()?**

It would be nice to simply instantiate an ST template with a root context node as a parameter and let ST traverse the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to share a solution that almost avoids duplicate work while using approach #1 from my question.

Step 1: create a model adaptor that uses reflection to call a method that does not conform getProperty()/isProperty()/hasProperty() standard.

```
private static class MyModelAdaptor extends ObjectModelAdaptor {
    @Override
    public synchronized Object getProperty(Interpreter interp, ST self, Object o, Object property, String propertyName) throws STNoSuchPropertyException {
        try {
            return super.getProperty(interp, self, o, property, propertyName);
        } catch (STNoSuchPropertyException noProperty) {
            final Class<?> cls = o.getClass();
            try {
                return cls.getMethod(propertyName).invoke(o);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw noProperty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Step 2: Register model adaptors

```
public static STGroup registerAdaptors(STGroup stg) {
    final MyModelAdaptor adaptor = new MyModelAdaptor();
    for (final Class<?> cls : MyParser.class.getDeclaredClasses()) {
        if (isSubclassOf(cls, ParserRuleContext.class)) {
            stg.registerModelAdaptor(cls, adaptor);
        }
    }
    return stg;
}
```

Step 3: implement isSubclassOf() method so that registerAdaptors() compiles:

```
private static boolean isSubclassOf(Class<?> cls, Class<?> superCls) {
    while (cls != null) {
        if (cls == superCls) {
            return true;
        }
        cls = cls.getSuperclass();
    }
    return false;
}
```